# Package installation error in Windows Universal Application

Tags: c#

When I try to make a new windows universal application, there is a package installation error. The package name is NuGet package.

Thanks in advance.
I am also attaching a screenshot of the error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Stj.png

Comment: Are you working with dotNet core?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio:

1. Project (pulldown)--> Manage NuGet Packages
2. Search box, type `Microsoft.NetCore`
3. Seventh entry will be `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform`
4. Click on this.  On the right side select `Install`.
5. A dialog box might come up, hit OK.

Once installed, recompile your app and there should be no errors.

Alternatively

1. Go to `Package Manager console`
2. Type: `Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform`